# Setting min max values for the Horizontal Axis on a Google Sheets chart

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with an embedded chart. I am able to add min/max values that display on the chart for the vertical axis, but not the horizontal.

Here are the details for the verticle axis:

[image]

But I don't have min/max options for the horizontal axis:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Min-Max option will only appear if the defined X-axis range contains only numeric values:

I was able to reproduce this with a sample table. My X-axis range is A3:A6.

[image]

When numeric values are used for the X-axis range:

[image]

Comment: The fact this is not supported for date-times is embarassingly annoying.